# Class of finite quotient affine space in Grothendieck ring of varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory, grothendieck-rings

Let $G$ be a finite group acting linearly on affine space $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ over $k = \mathbb{C}$. Since the action is linear, it can be extended to an action of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, which is connected, and therefore the induced action on cohomology $H_c^k(\mathbb{A}^n_k;\mathbb{Z})$ must be trivial. In particular, this shows that the Hodge–Deligne polynomials of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ and the GIT quotient $\mathbb{A}_k^n \;//\; G$ both equal $(uv)^n \in \mathbb{Z}[u, v]$.

Now, a more general invariant than the Hodge–Deligne polynomial is the class of a variety in the Grothendieck ring of varieties $\operatorname{K}(\operatorname{Var}_k)$.
My question is: is it true that

$$
[\mathbb{A}^n_k \;//\; G] \overset{?}{=} [\mathbb{A}^n_k]
$$

in $\operatorname{K}(\operatorname{Var}_k)$ (with still $k = \mathbb{C}$)? I can show this equality for $G$ abelian, but have not yet found a counterexample for $G$ non-abelian. Furthermore, I have seen examples (Saltman) of a finite group $G$ acting on $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ such that the quotient is not a rational variety, but I'm not sure if that yields a counterexample here.

**Edit:** apparently (see Jason Starr's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425763/class-of-finite-quotient-affine-space-in-grothendieck-ring-of-varieties#comment1094418_425763)) the answer is no in general. What about if we restrict to the symmetric group $G = S_n$?

Comment: Saltman's examples (and similar examples by Bogomolov, Ojanguren, et al.) are not even *stably rational*.  Now apply Larsen-Lunts.

Comment: About your Edit: do you mean for the standard action of $S_n$ on $\Bbb{A}^n$? Then the quotient is *isomorphic* to $\Bbb{A}^n$...

Comment: @JasonStarr: Larsen-Lunts is for smooth projective varieties, and it's not immediately applicable here, as the quotient is not smooth. That is, if $[U] = \mathbf{L}^n$ for a quasi-projective variety $U$ we may not immediately deduce that $U$ is stably rational.

Comment: @EvgenyShinder I believe there is a "Kirwan desingularization" of $\mathbb{A}^n$ (or perhaps something simpler) that makes the action "pseudoreflective" while only changing the class in the Grothendieck group by an integer-coefficient polynomial in $\mathbb{L}$.  Now we can apply Larsen-Lunts to the group quotient (which is smooth by Chevalley-Shephard-Todd).

Comment: @abx No, I mean any linear action

Comment: @JasonStarr: I am not sure what you mean exactly; however I don't think we can blow up $\mathbb{A}^n$ to make the quotient by the given linear action smooth. I think it's false already for cyclic quotients of $\mathbb{A}^2$. Probably you meant something else.

Comment: Actually, $\mathbb{A}^2$ is the only case where I am sure that this does work: just resolve the isolated quotient singularities on the quotient variety and then form the fiber product of that resolution and of the quotient morphism.